# Execute a .efi file from within the standard UEFI Shell

Tags: uefi

I have booted the UEFI shell using a binary that is distributed as part of TianoCore / EDK2. From this shell, is there a command to manually execute/boot some other .efi file?

Answer (score 1):

The .efi file *is* the command, just like you would run an .exe from within the Cmd shell in Windows.

However, you'll probably need to `cd` first into the directory, as some versions of the UEFI Shell don't recognize full paths as commands.

For example:

```
Shell> fs0:
fs0:\> cd EFI\grub
fs0:\EFI\grub> grubx64.efi
Shell> fs0:
fs0:\> cd Arch
fs0:\Arch\> vmlinuz.efi initrd=\Arch\initramfs.img root=/dev/sda2 rw
```